# Magento 2.2.2 Newsletter subscription - Something went wrong with the subscription

Tags: email, newsletter, magento2.2.2

[image]

I have this problem with subscription of newsletter but the address is successfully stored in the Database.

I have magento 2.2.2 fresh installation on server and allows php to send emails.

system log says

> main.CRITICAL: Exception message: Unable to send mail. 
>   Trace: #0 /var/www/html/projectName/vendor/magento/module-newsletter/Controller/Subscriber/NewAction.php(136): Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber->subscribe('test@domain...')

Mail sending settings
[image]

Can someone help me on fix this error.

Comment: is email working on ur server ?

Comment: php email working on my server

Comment: mail("someone@example.com","My subject",'test'); are u able to recive any email send by this php function

Comment: Have u configurable Mail server on Magento 2?

Answer (score 2):

**It is s genius error as your mail server is not working.
Your mail server is not able to fire mail.
Please check ur server setting.**

Comment: Sorry, The problem was that I didn't realize that magento uses php-mail function.